# Stop mapView over-scroll

Tags: android

I need my mapView to stop moving exactly when the user lifts the finger as i catch the current map state on the up event. By default if you swipe with your finger on the map, it will tend to keep it's momentum in that direction.
Thank you! :)

Comment: Hi, I too facing this issue. Did you found the solution?

Comment: No, all that I know is that you must stop the onFling. Get back if you have it right. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom implementation of `mapView` and implement `OnGestureListener` then override the on fling method:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                       float velocityY) {        
    return false;
}
```

This should have the desired effect.

Comment: Hei! Thank you for your response. I can't find the onFling superclass method :)

Comment: Sorry, you have to implement OnGestureListener. Answer edited. I can't test this right now, but will have a look later.

Comment: i will implement it in the weeks to come and get back to you.

Comment: You have to return true from the onFling method: it means that the event has been consumed and it doesn't propagate it to the default listener, hence it nulls the fling effect.